# Regex to get article ID from url

Tags: c#, regex

My url looks like:

```
www.example.com/a-292-some-text-here  // 292
www.example.com/a-2-asdfss       // 2
www.example.com/a-44-333      // 44
```

I need a regex to get the 292 from the url.

The ID will always be an integer.

i am using C#.

Comment: Will there always be the `a-` in front of it? Can you give some more examples of possible URLs?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) with `@"\d+"`:

```
string input = "www.example.com/a-292-some-text-here";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+");
if (match.Success)
{
    int id = int.Parse(match.Value);
    // Use the id...
}
else
{
    // Error!
}
```

Comment: @Blankman: I believe that the code I provided above gives you what you want for each of your example inputs.